# How to convert multiple list to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Below are 4 lists

- parent_list are keys
- parent_keys are keys
- rest 3 are values

```
parent_list= ['emp1', 'emp2', 'emp3']
parent_keys= ['name', 'id', 'salary']
emp1_value = ['A', '100', '$10,000']
emp2_value = ['B', '101', '$9,000']
emp3_value = ['C', '102', '$9,500']
```

I need to convert it into the dictionary

Expected Output:-

```
{'emp1':{'name':'A', 'id':'SG101', 'sal':$10,000}, 
'emp2':{'name':'B', 'id':'SG102', 'sal':$9,000}, 
'emp3':{'name':'C', 'id':'SG103', 'sal':$9,500}}
```

Code is below

```
dict(zip(parent_list,(parent_keys, emp1_value)))
```

My current output

```
{'emp1': ['name', 'id', 'salary'], 'emp2': ['A', '100', '$10,000']}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) inside *dictionary comprehension* to achieve this as:

```
parent_list= ['emp1', 'emp2', 'emp3']
parent_keys= ['name', 'id', 'salary']
emp1_value = ['A', '100', '$10,000']
emp2_value = ['B', '101', '$9,000']
emp3_value = ['C', '102', '$9,500']

# Additional list, to hold `emp*_value` together
employee_values = [
    emp1_value,
    emp2_value,
    emp3_value
]

my_dict = {key: dict(zip(parent_keys, employee_values[i])) for i, key in enumerate(parent_list)}
```

where `my_dict` will contain your desired dict as:

```
{'emp2': {'salary': '$9,000', 'name': 'B', 'id': '101'}, 'emp3': {'salary': '$9,500', 'name': 'C', 'id': '102'}, 'emp1': {'salary': '$10,000', 'name': 'A', 'id': '100'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
d = {}
for idx, emp in enumerate([emp1_value, emp2_value, emp3_value]):
    d[parent_list[idx]]=dict(zip(parent_keys, emp))
```

---

**d:**

```
{'emp1': {'name': 'A', 'id': '100', 'salary': '$10,000'},
 'emp2': {'name': 'B', 'id': '101', 'salary': '$9,000'},
 'emp3': {'name': 'C', 'id': '102', 'salary': '$9,500'}}
```